# Upload Multi-APK app to Huawei AppGallery?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

I'm trying to upload my app to **Huawei AppGallery Connect**, the app is published as **Multi-APK** to reduce its size (not using app bundle to avoid being signed by the store)

Here is my final multiple apk files :

[image]

I found [this official video](https://youtu.be/BWiw6Zr_r5c) by Huawei AppGallery explaining the **Multi-APK**, but I couldn't find any option to upload multiple APKs as the upload form accepts only 1 APK, as in this image :

[image]

Could you please explain if it's possible or not, and how to do it ?

Comment: Currently, the Multi-APK App Distribution is available only to invited users. I will update you with the status soon.

Answer (score 2):

The Huawei AppGallery Connect now can support Multiple-APK, but it's still in beta stage. You can try to send mail to agconnect@huawei.com to apply for use.